# Make a flexbox match the width of its parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve this specific design with no luck:

[image]

**The black box should control the width of `#container` (yellow bordered).**
Then, the container of `#flex` (a flexbox that contains the red divs) will resize to match the dimensions of its parent.

The code I came up with is the following:

```css
#container {
  border: 4px solid #f1c40f;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: white;
}
#title {
  padding: .5em .75em;
  background: #2c3e50;
  display: inline-flex;
}
#flex {
  display: flex;
}
#icon {
  background: #c0392b;
  padding: .5em .75em;
}
#content {
  background: #e74c3c;
  padding: .5em .75em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">I should set the width of the container!</div>
    <div id="flex">
      <div id="icon">
        icon
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu eleifend sem. Cras elit odio, faucibus vel tortor nec, lacinia accumsan enim. Aenean eget vulputate ante. Integer quis condimentum magna. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse imperdiet eget magna vitae rhoncus. Vestibulum fringilla accumsan accumsan. Duis facilisis lobortis scelerisque. Pellentesque at erat porta, scelerisque nisl in, volutpat sem. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus enim augue, tempus et facilisis id, lobortis eu urna. Aenean volutpat risus dolor, ac volutpat enim euismod ac. Ut id rutrum felis.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the snippet, `#flex` makes the `#container` wider than it should be. I tried `#container {display: inline-flex;}`, I tried to apply `flex-basis: 0%;` and `flex-shrink: 1;` to the children of the flexbox, but nothing seems to change this behaviour.

How can I make `#flex` match the width of `#title`?

Thanks!

Comment: you can also play with flex-grow, set it to 0

Comment: @TemaniAfif unfortunately that doesn't seem to help

Comment: @Itay Ganor just remove `display: inline-flex` from `#title`

Comment: @MerajKhan That's not what I meant. I need `#title` to set the width, so `#flex` will match this width. In this case the `inline-flex` of `#title` is meaningless

Comment: @Itay Ganor then add `display: flex;  flex-direction: column;` to #container

Comment: check the last update of the accepted answer, this is what you need

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should modify your container:

```
#container {

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  border: 4px solid #f1c40f;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: white;
}
```

then you can give the container a `width`.

http://jsbin.com/vufolodowe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: `can give the container a width` --> do you think there is any issue if we set a width ? It will be trivial and obvious and you don't even need to modify the code.